# Rails 3 + ActiveAdmin - filtering a has_many association from the parent model index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, scope, activeadmin

I have two models:

```
class Worker
  has_many :location_preferences
end

class LocationPreference
  attr_accessible :location
  belongs_to :worker
end
```

In the ActiveAdmin Worker index, I want to be able to filter workers by having location preferences with a selected `:location` (or, ideally, checkboxes for finding workers by multiple location preferences).

In other contexts I have been able to filter on the child index doing something like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Account

filter :user_last_name
```

...to find accounts owned by a User with the provided `last_name`. But I'm not having much luck filtering a parent class by the attributes of the child class. I could make a scope button but I already have a bunch of scope buttons for this AA resource and don't want to crowd it. Plus it seems like there should be some way to do this without having to write a scope for every imaginable filter option.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `has_many :locations, through: :location_preferences` would allow a filter for locations to be added to the `Worker`.

```
class Worker
  has_many :location_preferences

  # Add has many through relation
  has_many :locations, through: :location_preferences
end
```

Then the ActiveAdmin resource can be defined with the location filter.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Worker do
  filter :locations, as: :check_boxes
end
```